# How to take advantage of Image caching while keeping track of when images have changed?

Tags: php, image, file, caching, browser-cache

On one of my sites, I simply store my users images as '1.jpg' in their user folder.  This means that whenever they change their profile pic, the filename stays the same.

I've been wanting to take advantage of image caching so that the same old pic doesn't get downloaded over and over again whenever a user's profile is viewed and re-viewed, but at the same time, I want my users' browsers to download the new one if it has changed.

How could I do this in PHP?

Comment: Answered here:  http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/32481/is-it-worth-it-to-change-my-entire-user-images-file-structure-to-take-advantage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered here:  https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/32481/is-it-worth-it-to-change-my-entire-user-images-file-structure-to-take-advantage

---

One commonly used solution is to make your image URLs look something like this:

```
http://www.example.com/path/to/images/1.jpg?v=123456
```

Here, `/path/to/images/1.jpg` is the actual URL path of the image, while `?v=123456` is just a dummy query staring tacked onto the end of the URL.  The query string can be anything — a version number, a timestamp, a hash of the image content — as long as you change it whenever the image changes, and keep it the same when it doesn't.

The trick is that the web server, when asked to serve such a URL, will ignore the query string, since the URL in fact points to a static file.  But to the user's browser (and to any proxies in between), URLs with different query strings will be completely different, and so any change to the query string forces the browser to reload the file.

Thus, you can configure your web server to send `Expires` and `Cache-Control` HTTP headers to allow indefinite caching, safe in the knowledge that you can force a reload by changing the query string.  One way to do that, if you're using Apache with [mod_expires](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_expires.html), is to put an `.htaccess` file in your image directory with the lines:

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
```

This technique is used by many popular websites.  For example, if you look at the HTML source of this very page, you'll find that the style sheet for it is loaded from a URL like this:

```
http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/all.css?v=7cd8ea9d6f1e
```

Here, the `?v=7cd8ea9d6f1e` is a dummy query string just like I described above; you can confirm that by changing it and seeing that it indeed still returns the same file.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest fix would be that each user's profile pick is assigned a random name GUID.jpg. Whenever they change their profile pic assign them a new GUID.

Now you can server this profile pic with instructions to clients to cache it forever.

Comment: Wouldn't I then have to keep track of every single pic that gets uploaded?  Where/how would I store the random names?  Right now, I know exactly where to find/call every user's profile pic since it's just their user folder / 1.jpg.

Comment: Each pictures goes to their profile folder but gets a random name. You can either clean up older pictures in the profile folder or just return the last created one.

Comment: The problem with that is that they are allowed to upload more than one pic, so how would I keep track of all those random filenames, and which ones belong to which users?

Comment: How about upload profile pictures /userfolder/profile/ and other pictures to /userfolder/. This way you know that the last created file in /userfolder/profile is their profile picture

Comment: But what if they upload an extra pic after their profile pic, but which isn't their profile pic?  It seems that no matter you how cut it, if you wish to allow multiple pics and do your solution, you will need to store every single filename in the DB.  So my question is, is it worth it for me to change the entire file structure of my site, plus add the DB element, for benefit of eternal caching and automatic re-downloading upon new upload?

Answer (score 0):

E-Tagging, Last-modified, basically headers that enable browsers to decide if a resource, i.e the profile pic, has changed and whether or not to download it from your server or retrieve it from cache.

Might I suggest using php to call the picture instead of directly linking it?

`<?php
$lmt = filemtime($_GET['file']);
$etag = md5($lmt); 
header('Content-type: application/x-javascript');
header("Cache-Control: max-age=3600");
header("Last-Modified: ".gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", $lmt)." GMT"); 
header("ETag: ".'"'.$etag.'"');
if(@strtotime($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) == $lmt || trim($_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']) == $etag) { 
    header("HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified");
    exit; 
}
?>`

Content then would be loaded below this code segment